React-hook-form and typescript problem with error naming when using usefieldArray. The errors show correctly, but problem with type 'FieldError'
I have a react-hook-form which uses data that has two objects in the array. When using useFieldArray there is a typescript error on defining the error in the JSX element:-
"Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'FieldError | Merge<FieldError, FieldErrorsImpl>'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'FieldError | Merge<FieldError, FieldErrorsImpl>'"
The errors show correctly in the console.
Any help would be much apprectiated.
Here is the code for my problem codebox
